# Is it portable to take the address of malloc(), realloc() and free()?

Tags: c, standards

Per the standard, is it safe to take the address of `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()`?

For example,

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
void * (*my_malloc)(size_t) = &malloc;
```

Corollary, is it possible in standards-compliant C that the implementation uses a macro for `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.  The standard library is allowed to define function-like macros for any of its functions, but they must also be available as functions.

C17 7.1.4 (1)

> Any
> function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined
> in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the
> techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. Any
> macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in
> parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of
> a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library
> function even if it is also defined as a macro. [189]

> [189] This means that an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function, even if it also provides a
> macro for that function.

So in short, the library's header is allowed to have something like

```
void *malloc(size_t);
#define malloc(s) __fancy_internal_malloc((s) + 47 | 0x14 * 3)
```

and so then you can do any of

```
void *p = malloc(10); // invokes the macro if there is one
void *q = (malloc)(10); // definitely calls the function, not the macro
void *(*allocator)(size_t) = &malloc; // takes address of the function
#undef malloc
void *r = malloc(10); // definitely the function
```

Of course, the function and the macro must both provide whatever behavior the standard promises (though as  Eric Postpischil comments, they do not have to behave identically so long as each is conformant).  In particular, it must be safe to allocate with the macro and free with the function, or vice versa.  Also, such a macro must evaluate each of its arguments exactly once, so `p = malloc(s++);` is safe for either the function or the macro.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: True, I spoke imprecisely.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) The quoted standard is C17; does this rule hold for previous standards, too? If so, how far back?

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED: It was in C89, see [4.1.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.1.6).  I'll leave it to you to check the ones in between if you want to make sure.